# Swift Scrollview scroll so that button is right above keyboard when keyboard appears

Tags: swift, scrollview

I have tried literally every solution on the internet to get this answer, and none of them work without bugs. I have a stackview embedded in a scrollview, and I want the `signInButton` to be right above the keyboard.

Here is my current attempted solution:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary?,
        let keyboardInfo = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
            return
    }
    let keyboardSize = keyboardInfo.cgRectValue.size
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0.0)
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    var rect = self.view.frame
    rect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    var frame = self.signInButton.frame
    frame.size.height += 50
    self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
}
@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
}
```

But this does not come close to working on all screen sizes. While the button always appears sometimes it appears way above the keyboard, and other times slightly above. And when the keyboard disappears on some screens it doesn't work either. I'm curious if anyone knowledgeable can give a robust answer that many can use for this ubiquitous problem. Swift 5 please.

I know I can use a tableview, but I find it incredibly sad that iOS does not have a clear, alternative working solution without embedding everything in a tableview.

Thanks!

Comment: Don’t look at the keyboard size. Look at its frame, convert to the coordinate system of the button superview, and think about how that relates to the button frame.

Comment: Also you are not scrolling. Merely changing the content inset is not going to do you any good. You need to change the content offset, ie scroll.

Comment: Can't you just use a tableView ? (static tableview in a tableViewController if its just a login screen) Its much better and easier than messing with scrollView.

Comment: I probably could use a tableview but its really not the most direct thing to use for this use case

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems and i fixed it by using this. (probably not the best way, but it works)

Add these in viewDidLoad()

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)  

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboarddismissedlogin(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("keyboarddismissedlogin"), object: nil)
```

Define those 3 functions

```
// MARK: - KeyboardON
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
           let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
           let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
           let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
           let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
           TableBottomConstraint.constant = TableBottomConstraint.constant + keyboardHeight
           extraFunctions.keyboardHeight = Int(keyboardHeight)
       }
// MARK: - keyboardOFFheight
       @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification) {


           let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
           let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
           let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
           let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

           if TableBottomConstraint.constant > keyboardHeight
           {
           TableBottomConstraint.constant = TableBottomConstraint.constant - keyboardHeight

           }

    }

// MARK: - Keyboard Dismiss
        @objc func keyboarddismissedlogin(notification: Notification) {

            TableBottomConstraint.constant = TableBottomConstraint.constant - CGFloat(extraFunctions.keyboardHeight)
        }
```

Here you have to make an outlet of your table or scroll view's bottom constraint.

```
extraFunctions.keyboardHeight
```

is simply a struct that i created to store the keyboard height. (you can simply create a variable instead of struct - > variable. I did it just for the sake of naming it)

This will simply move your view UP from the bottom when keyboard appears and changes back to original position when keyboard disappears.

**All this works , assuming that your BUTTON is at the bottom of your view.**

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but this is industry code and I'm trying not to hack around

Answer (score 0):

I donot fully get your question. In my case, I put the constraint to the bottom of the button, and set its constant when the keyboard appear/ dissappaear.

```
@IBOutlet weak var edittingBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@objc func showKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            let keyBoardHeight = keyboardRectangle.size.height
            edittingBottomConstraint.constant = -keyBoardHeight
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I click a UITextField I want the scrollview to scroll so that a button, the submit button, is directly above the keyboard on every phone size

Comment: This does not really work, since the scrollview prefers to squash other views than to scroll

Comment: If use scrollView, then set the contentOffset and also the contentSize of scrollView so it can scroll. It is not the good way, so if you know better way, please share with me. Thanks

Comment: The only way to do this apparently is to use a TableView